# How to create simple pagination in PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, html, pagination

Below is my Code.

```
<?php

$folder_name=$_GET['folder_name'];
$dirname = "customized_kits/images/";

$images = glob($dirname."*");
 $filecount = count( $images );
$i=0;

for($i=0;$i<200;$i++) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-2">  <div class="photos">
        <div id="images1">
            <a href=# data-lightbox="roadtrip">
            <?php
            if($filecount>$i) {
                $filename = substr($images[$i], strrpos($images[$i], '/') + 1);   
    echo '<a href="'.$images[$i].'" target="_blank"><img src="'.$images[$i].'" style="width:150px;height:150px" /></a><br/>';
            ?>

            <a href="#" class="del_photo1" style="color:#C20B0B;font-size:20px;" onclick="theFunction('<?php echo $filename; ?>','<?php echo $folder_name; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>

            <?php } else {
                echo '<a ><img style="width:150px;height:150px;background-color:#eee" /></a>';
            } ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Here I created 200 boxes with foreach loop I want to show 20 divs for single page and with help of pagination I want to show other divs.I searched in many websites I didnt get exact answer please help me to get out of this issue.

Comment: Can you please post the entire code (initialization of $images)

Comment: Check my edited code

Comment: See response from @georoot it's appropriate ! Just missing links

Answer (score 1):

Okay so from your code you can have 200 values of `$i` and you want to paginate them in segments of 20. Let us start off by adding a script above your code to get the range that needs to be displayed. Page number comes as a `GET` parameter in number. ex `example.com/feeds?number=2`.

```
<?php
$pageno = $_GET['number']; // Page number from frontend
// Now this value will give you 1,2,3 etc
$start = $pageno*20;
// $start contains the initial offset or the value of `$i` from to start
for($i=$start;$i<$start+20;$i++) {
    // Will only show 20 elements on the page
}
?>
```

Remember this is a very basic example. Although i would recommend using range in `sql` query instead so you don't have to load the complete dataset in each query.

#### More explanation

Suppose you have `M` results and you want to show `N` results on each page, the results on page `x` would start from `x*N` to `x*(N+1)` pure math here. In your code you are iterating `$i` over the whole loop rather just iterate over that specific range to get results. The value of `x` is the example is the page number that we get from `number` in `GET` verb.

Comment: @KavyaShree check now i added more explanation to that

Comment: If I use like this how can I go next and previous button I want pagination model.It should not be like URL get pagenumber